# Paging with SQL Pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table, row-number

I have this Query :

```
WITH PageIndex AS 
( SELECT TOP 6  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UserID) as RowIndex,
* FROM [dbo].[vw_EngProfilePivot] WHERE NeedJob='True' ) SELECT * FROM PageIndex
 WHERE RowIndex > 0 AND RowIndex <= 6
```

---

[dbo].[vw_EngProfilePivot] Design :

```
SELECT
UserID,
MAX(CASE WHEN PropertyDefinitionID = 49 THEN PropertyValue END) AS Gender, MAX(CASE WHEN PropertyDefinitionID = 52 THEN PropertyValue END) AS City, 
MAX(CASE WHEN PropertyDefinitionID = 59 THEN PropertyValue END) AS EngDegreeID, MAX(CASE WHEN PropertyDefinitionID = 60 THEN PropertyValue END) AS EngMajorID, 
MAX(CASE WHEN PropertyDefinitionID = 57 THEN PropertyValue END) AS NeedJob, MAX(CASE WHEN PropertyDefinitionID = 58 THEN PropertyValue END) AS ExperienceYears
FROM            dbo.UserProfile
GROUP BY UserID
_________________________________________________________________________
```

---

now,the first script returned 4 rows and the problem in performance when I pass page size more than "4" as example "6" it takes 800 ms while if the page size was 4(actual result - 4 rows) the execution takes less than 100ms any explanation please?

Comment: It will never be fast, as the query engine has to first return all rows from `vw_EngProfilePivot` before applying `WHERE NeedJob='True'` and afterwards `ROW_NUMBER()`. Data dictionary designs, while flexible, suffer from performance problems in relational DBs.

Comment: Assuming that your `PropertyDefinitionID `s are unique per user, I would simply convert the query into `INNER JOIN`s.

Comment: Thank you, the engine will select only 6 rows regardless where clause, the problem in the performance only if you send page size more than the result set